# transparent background screen that is constantly on top

Tags: android, android-activity, background, overlay, transparent

I tried almost everything just to simply create an transparent overlaying activity that is constantly in the background. All it should do is just be there and it should not capture any click events but simply pass them through the underlaying whatsoever activity. A lot of post appear to have the solution. But for me, none of them worked so far.
(see
[How to create an overlay canvas with propagation of touch events to the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267945/how-to-create-an-overlay-canvas-with-propagation-of-touch-events-to-the-home-scr)

[Popup over incoming-call screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699257/popup-over-incoming-call-screen)
)

In onCreate of the activity ive tried each combination of these to make it work:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE); 
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);     
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
```

Still, the screen only appears to let through touch events, but no click events. So, for example, when Im in the default home screen and launch my app, I can't open any app, but I can drag apps and select them strangely enough.

Please help, I have not found any solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

If the user does not interact with the application directly, is there a reason you are using an activity, and not a service?

Comment: I'm the creator of Super Dimmer, which does just this. I am using a service to overlay a shade on the user's screen. If the user does not need to interact with the screen, but instead, all the calculations,etc is done transparent to the user, use a service instead.

Comment: Well, I want to present an image to the user when a call comes in. But this image should not block click events because the user still needs to be able to to interact with the incoming or outgoing phone dialog.